# wget command to download whole mp4 video from website

Tags: linux, wget

If you would please help me.

I'm new to wget but i've tried few commands and I got it to download directly to server. But i'm only getting part of the video not the whole video.

Example Link.
https://openload.co/embed/4sxKGh-zjVGvZjUu/Autopsia+e+Xhejn+Doe+2016+HD.mp4

I've used wget link then i tried -r -A.mp4 link only a part or whole page downloads but video is only a part.

Can someone please explain how am I able to acheive the whole video.

Much appreciated.
SX

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get install youtube-dl` and then simply `$ youtube-dl URL`. If you really want to use `wget` change the User-Agent (-U 'Mozilla') to pretend being a real user.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use axel -an 100 link_url, this will use 100 thread to download the link response, it will be soon download finish than the wget.
axel  need to be install by apt-get or source code in CentOS